# Deleting draft PR's

Tags: github, pull-request

I know github generally has a rule where PR's and stuff can be closed, but never deleted to preserve history, unless there is something very necessary about it (such as private keys being included in the PR by accident, etc.). I was wondering, however, if draft PR's can be deleted. Sometimes I use it for certain CI/CD testing, and I end up closing them, but they can start cluttering up my PR history. Since they were never converted to a full, real PR, is that a thing we can do without contacting github support?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently no.  Draft PRs are treated like regular PRs and cannot be deleted without contacting support.  https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository. They only delete them if there is sensitive data.

You might want to setup a separate repo just for CI/CD testing if you are trying to test configurations like Actions.  That would keep your main repo from getting cluttered.

If you are creating draft PRs to run tests, that could indicate your tests are difficult (or slow) to run locally.  I'm just assuming though.  I know that's why I sometimes reply on CI/CD instead of local testing.